# Using gettext with local catalog has no effect

Tags: c++, gettext

I am [following an official i8n example](http://www.async.com.br/~kiko/gettext.html) for local catalog repositories with gettext:

```
#include <libintl.h>
#include <iostream>
#define _(str) gettext(str)

int
main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "pt_PT");
    bindtextdomain ("messages", "/home/pasousa/temp/i18n_test/lang/");
    textdomain ("messages");

    std::cout << _("Hello world!") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The Portuguese translation strings are contained in `./lang/pt_PT/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`.  But if I use all this code I do not get the `Hello World` message translated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Be sure to include all the information, so that would mean the contents of your `messages.mo` file *(which should be trimmed down to just "Hello World!" for the sake of the example)*.  Also, it could be helpful if you checked to see what the return results of the calls are... I note that `bindtextdomain` may return a pointer to a `char*` for a directory or NULL--for instance, and sets `errno` if there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the locale you set is valid - If you don't set a valid locale in `setlocale`, then glibc will assume you're running in the `C` or `POSIX` locale and ignore the values that were specified in the `bindtextdomain` and simply return the unlocalized values. This seems to be a somewhat undocumented behaviour of gettext.

You probably want to set the locale to `pt_PT.UTF-8` instead of simply `pt_PT`.

in my case, when I tried, I got:

```
char *from_setlocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_PT");
char *checked_setlocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
std::cout << (from_setlocale ? from_setlocale : "NULL") << std::endl << (checked_setlocale ? checked_setlocale : "NULL") << std::endl;
```

but that's because I don't have the Portuguese locale installed. When I set a locale that I have installed (`en_IE.UTF-8`) then I get some useful output:

```
char *from_setlocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_IE.UTF-8");
char *checked_setlocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
std::cout << (from_setlocale ? from_setlocale : "NULL") << std::endl << (checked_setlocale ? checked_setlocale : "NULL") << std::endl;
```

And in addition, I get a localized value from the message file that I had generated.

Comment: I've tried that and also tested that the locale works, but I still only get system settings.

Comment: You have, in all likelehood got the `LANG` or `LANGUAGE` environment variable set, which is overriding the attempt to use the other language.